# Executing code makes the program stop responding

Tags: c#

Very new to programming and I need help solving an issue. After launching my program, it would say that the program has stopped responding and immediately closes. Here is the code itself :

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="587.615">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Programme de devinette" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="355" Height="56" FontSize="22" FontFamily="Segoe WP Black"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="BoiteChiffre" Height="23" Margin="228,103,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
    <Label Content="Entrez un chiffre" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="216,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164" FontSize="18"/>
    <Button Content="Nombre random" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="77,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="109" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Button Content="Verification" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="424,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.055,0.428" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
    <Button Content="Quitter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="253,201,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

</Grid>
```

and this is the code associated with that window :

```
namespace WpfApplication6
{
/// <summary>
/// Logique d'interaction pour Window2.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int random1;
     private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //random
    {
        Random chiffrealeatoire = new Random();
        random1 = (chiffrealeatoire.Next(0, 20));
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //quit
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }

    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //veri
    {

    }

     private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(BoiteChiffre.Text) < random1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Too low");
        }
        if (Convert.ToInt32(BoiteChiffre.Text) > random1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Too high");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Congratulations");          
        }
    }
}
```

The code is supposed to have 3 buttons : One that exits the program, one that assigns a hidden random number between 0-20 when clicked (user has to guess this number) and one that check if the number that user enters matches the randomly generated number. If the number doesn't match, the program tells the user if his number is too high to too low. As I said earlier, my program crashes after launching it and I can't find what the problem is. All help is appriciated, thanks.

PS : The window looks something like this

[image]

Comment: At first sight, it looks like an unhandled exception. you should try adding a [try-catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) block around your `TextBox_TextChanged` event handler

Comment: @MatiasCicero I'd suggest you post that as an answer, since that is the problem. The TextChanged event will raise (and cause the exception) when the form is loaded and "TextBox" (default text) is written to the TextBox.

Comment: What exactly does Avast have anything to do with this? I ran this on another computer that didn't have Avast and got the same result.

Comment: @Dr.Roflcopter "Uninstall Avast" is a joke...

Comment: Try initilize `random1` as: `int random1 = 0`

Comment: @HansPassant I remember seeing many such answers from you over the past week(s). If it's not, as I hope, a joke, do you have any pointers to the reason behind this behavior ?

Comment: _[Well thanks to Hans Passant, I found out it is Avast's fault. Adding my project folder to exceptions, has fixed the problem](http://tinyurl.com/oq6uheg);_ and  _[Finally figured it out. It's my lovely antivirus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33908905/weird-issue-with-c-sharp-console-app-on-a-specific-machine/33920358#33920358);_ and _[Problem was found to be Avast preventing the executable from running properly](http://tinyurl.com/h2fhykt)_.  All recent problems.  Whether it applies here is an exercise for the reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code block does 2 things:

1. It moves your logic from `private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)` to `private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //veri` since you don't want to validate every time the text changes but only when the user clicks the "Verification" button.
2. `Convert.ToInt32` was replaced with a `int.TryParse` which returns a boolean value (true/false) indicating wether it was successful in converting the text into an integer (int) and writing it into the num variable (true) or if it failed to do so (false). The `return;` forces the function to end execution since the `int.TryParse` failed to convert.

You may want to change it to something like this instead:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //veri
{
    int num;
    if (!int.TryParse(BoiteChiffre.Text, out num))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Must enter an integer");
    }
    else if (num < random1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Too low");
    }
    else if (num > random1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Too high");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations");
    }
}
```

By the way, in WPF there are some better ways to do validations and better user experience, you can google **WPF validation** yourself. I helped you search some:

- [How to: Implement Binding Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms753962(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [Simple Validation in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/690130/Simple-Validation-in-WPF)
- [Validation in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/863291/Validation-in-WPF)

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of _why_ OP's code was failing and _how_ your answer resolves it

Comment: This seems to have fixed the instant crashing problem, what exactly does the second and third line do? Although it did fix the crashing, another problem arises. The program instantly verifies if the number is correct right after I type in ONE number even though I did not click on verify yet. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Dr.Roflcopter, You can learn from some links in my updated answer.

Comment: @Lei Yang Thank you, I will consult it at this moment.

Comment: @Dr.Roflcopter "The program instantly verifies if the number is correct right after I type in ONE number even though I did not click on verify yet." That occurs because you implemented the validation in the text field's text changed event handler. Moving the login in the answer from `TextBox_TextChanged` which is triggered at every key stroke that affects the content of the text box to `Button_Click_2` which is triggered when you press the verify button.

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking here that you may need to set a default value in BoiteChiffre field.
Set it to 0, and make sure the code is not excuted if the field is empty or not a number.
You may be better using [Int23.tryparse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Convert()

Comment: did you vote me down because you know him or somethin? My answer is correct and faster by one minute.

Comment: I voted you down because your answer does not solve the problem. A default value **is** already set.

Comment: You have to read the entire answer, I said "Set it to 0, and make sure the code is not excuted if the field is empty or not a number".